# Contact form - make the "from" url not looking like an url in the body of the message to avoid msg to be considered as spam?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, contact-form

I have a contact form at the bottom of each page of my website. Messages are sent thanks to the code below. It works great but the fact that in the body of the message the URL from where the message was sent appears like this "From site: http://www.mywebsite.com/page2.htm" makes the message going to my spam items every time (I know I could flag it as non-spam etc.).

Is there a way to make the URL (retrieved by `. $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`
) not looking like an url in the body of the message i.e. but inputing spaces btw www and .com or any other solution?

Many thanks

**sendmessage.php:**

```
<?php
// Email Submit
// Note: filter_var() requires PHP >= 5.2.0
if ( isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['message']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {

  // detect & prevent header injections
  $test = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|to:)/i";
  foreach ( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
    if ( preg_match( $test, $val ) ) {
      exit;
    }
  }

  //send email
 mail( "contact@dfsdfds.com", "New message from: ".$_POST['name'], $_POST['message']."\nFrom site: ". $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "From:" . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n" . "BCC: dfds@gmail.com" );

}
?>
```

**scripts.js:**

```
// Contact Form
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contactfrm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var message = $("#message").val();
        var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&message=' + message;

        function isValidEmail(emailAddress) {
            var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
            return pattern.test(emailAddress);
        };
        if (isValidEmail(email) && (message.length > 1) && (name.length > 1)) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "sendmessage.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function() {
                    $('input[name="submit"]').hide();
                    $('.error').hide()
                    $('.success').fadeIn(1000);
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('.error').fadeIn(1000);
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Just train your spam filter? If you don't maintain multiple sites, you could as well just strip the whole domain part

Comment: Wanted to do this but since recipients will change regularly and will be out of my control that would not be a viable solution. But thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you need to cut off the http:// in front of the url, like this:

```
str_replace("http://", "", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])
```

If you want to put spaces between the . com (etc.) you could also do it with str_replace ([look up for detail](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)).
But I don't think you need the put spaces into the url, because most spam-filters scan for the http:// part for link-detection. Another reason why your EMail is filterd could be the short text or the unknown sending-server.

Comment: Thanks, will give a try. Where should I place this? (I'm a complete newbie in PHP) Many thanks

Comment: @Greg You replace `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` with the code above.